# Replace names inside a JSON string with ids in mySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table that has a pkey and a pvalue column.  One pkey value is "moderators" and its corresponding pvalue is a JSON string.  Currently the string looks like this:

```
 [{"name":"Joe Blow","number":"+15553271234"},{"name":"Jack Black","number":"+14352513511"},{"name":"Jack Black","number":"+15552341644"},{"name":"Amanda Brown","number":"+14446326620"}]
```

I want to write a one-off query to change the "name:" to "id:" and then change "Joe Blow" to the id that is looked up in another table.

I have seen a website on using JSON_REPLACE, but I don't see how that would work if I am going to be running this on every entry in the JSON string and all the keys are the same.  I would need to loop through the string, find the value of the first "name:", look up the corresponding id, and write that id back into the string in the place of value.

I am very new to JSON and sort of new to mySQL.  So far I have this:

```
 UPDATE preference SET pvalue = REPLACE(pvalue, '"name":', '"tid:"') AND REPLACE(pvalue, '$.name', 
     (SELECT id FROM transcribers WHERE name = '$.name')
 ) WHERE pkey = 'moderators';
```

When I run this query, pvalue is replaced with 0.

If I separate them into:

```
 UPDATE preference SET pvalue = REPLACE(pvalue, '"name":', '"tid:"') WHERE pkey = 'moderators';

 UPDATE preference SET pvalue = REPLACE(pvalue, '$.name', 
      (SELECT id FROM transcriber WHERE name = '$.name')
 ) WHERE pkey = 'moderators';
```

The first query works, but for the second query I get an error message `Column pvalue cannot be null.`

Comment: You must use nested replace: `SET field = REPLACE(REPLACE(field, 'old_name', 'new_name'), 'old_value', 'new_value')`.

Comment: @Akina, thank you, but I don't know how many times I need to replace.  I have a local database, but this would be run on the "real" database.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Do you want to replace `Jack Black` and `Amanda Brown` as well as `Joe Blow`?

Comment: *I don't know how many times I need to replace.* You must store ReplaceFrom/ReplaceTo in (temporary) table, join it to your table, and perform multi-table replace. if you have 8+ version, you may transfer source data as solid JSON object parsed using JSON_TABLE.

Comment: @Nick, version 5.7.3.
I want to replace every name with the corresponding ID that is looked up in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to my boss, I was told that it is too complicated to do via a query and to just do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like a´akina already said, use:

```
 UPDATE preference SET pvalue = REPLACE(REPLACE(pvalue, '"name":', '"tid":')
       , '$.name', (SELECT id FROM transcriber WHERE name = '$.name')
 ) WHERE pkey = 'moderators';
```

you can treat the json object as a text string

I repklaced

```
'"tid:"'
```

with

```
'"tid":'
```

or else you would have a problem with your json structure

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and accept if it works.

Comment: I keep getting a message that pvalue cannot be null.